# SASS compilation error with nth-child selector

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

So I did a bit of research around here and was unable to find an answer, so hopefully, somebody here can help me out...

I have the following SASS code

```
$column: 7;

table
{
  th:nth-child($column) 
  {
    // This does NOT compile
  } 
  th:nth-child(7) 
  {
    // This does compile
  }
}
```

Why is it that using the nth-child selector in combination with a variable does not compile within SASS? Is there any alternative I can go about using a *dynamic* value with the nth-child selector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A variable must be [interpolated](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) when used with a selector (e.g. as an argument to a functional pseudo-class). In your case, the syntax should look something like this:

```
$column: 7;

table
{
  th:nth-child(#{$column})
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```